# Remove last line in a DataGridView

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have a normal DataGridView.
Edit: I use "dgv.CellBorderStyle = DataGridViewCellBorderStyle.SunkenHorizontal;" to remove the line in the normal version.
[image]

And when i change the color to black the last row have a line in the bottom. No matter what "CellBorderStyle" i use the line is always there. I want to remove that line to make it looks like the white version.
[image]

Code for the black colors:

```
dgv.EnableHeadersVisualStyles = false;
dgv.ColumnHeadersDefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(53, 53, 53);
dgv.ColumnHeadersDefaultCellStyle.ForeColor = Color.FromArgb(215, 215, 215);
dgv.ColumnHeadersBorderStyle = DataGridViewHeaderBorderStyle.Sunken;
dgv.BackgroundColor = Color.FromArgb(53, 53, 53);
dgv.Font = new Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 9F, FontStyle.Regular);
dgv.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(53, 53, 53);
dgv.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.None;
dgv.CellBorderStyle = DataGridViewCellBorderStyle.SingleHorizontal;
```

Comment: [DataGridViewAdvancedBorderStyle Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridviewadvancedborderstyle)